# What is wrong with this c code line?

Tags: c

This line

```
double hdg_and_lee = cal_array[variation] +
                     normalize(corrected.hdg + (corrCalc.twa > 0 && corrCalc.twa < 180)
                     ? -abs(corrected.leeway) : abs(corrected.leeway));
```

returns the value of `cal_array[variation]`, which is clearly incorrect.  `corrected.leeway` happens to be 0 but `corrected.hdg` is 211, `variation` is 14 and that is what this line evaluates to.

I changed it to this, which works but I think should be the same as the line above.

```
double lee = (corrCalc.twa > 0 && corrCalc.twa < 180) ? -abs(corrected.leeway) : abs(corrected.leeway));
double hdg_and_lee;
hdg_and_lee  = cal_array[variation] + corrected.hdg + lee;
hdg_and_lee = normalize(hdg_and_lee);
```

I just can't see what I did wrong.

Here is normalize.  It just makes angle between 0 and 360;

```
double normalize(double angle){
    while (angle < 0) angle += 360;
    while (angle > 360) angle -= 360;
    return angle;
}
```

This is driving me nuts but of course I have a working alternative.  I just want to know what went wrong.

Comment: Why do you say that they are the same when they **clearly** aren't?

Comment: The two code snippets you provided are not equivalent. In the first, you add `cal_array[variation]` to the result of `normalize(...)` but in the second the sum of `cal_array[variation]` is passed in as part of the angle in `normalize(...)`.

Comment: I should have normalized the entire thing and made that correction but it doesn't change the fact the first line returns 14 and the second version returns 225.  Normalize does nothing on any of the cases given.

Comment: an option: `X ? -Y : Y` can be written as `Y * (X ? -1 : 1)`, or even `Y * (1 - 2*X)` if `X` is the result of a logical operator as it is here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
double hdg_and_lee = cal_array[variation] + normalize(corrected.hdg +  ((corrCalc.twa > 0 && corrCalc.twa < 180)? -abs(corrected.leeway) : abs(corrected.leeway)));
```

Check C Operator Precedence especially `+` vs. `?:`.